# Merge list of dicts

Tags: python

So, given a list of dictionaries in the following format:

```py
[
  {
    'prod_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_SP1', 
    'testing_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_DA1', 
    'project_adm': 'scisae', 
    'vdb': 'aPWH - cpi', 
    'db_name': 'cpi'
  }, 
  {    
    'prod_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_SP1', 
    'testing_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_DA1', 
    'project_adm': 'scisae', 
    'vdb': 'aPWH - aeis', 
    'db_name': 'asis'
  }
]
```

I would like to merge the dictionaries if `prod_instance`, `testing_instance`, and `project_adm` are equal.

i.e. The expected result of the above example

```py
[
  {
    'prod_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_SP1', 
    'testing_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_DA1', 
    'project_adm': 'scisae', 
    'data_sources': [
      {
        'vdb': 'aPWH - cpi', 
        'db_name': 'cpi'
      },
      {
        'vdb': 'aPWH - aeis', 
        'db_name': 'asis'
      }
    ]    
  }
]
```

Sure, I can do it with a double `for` loop, but (1) it is O(n<sup>2</sup>) and (2) it is long and ugly.

Can anyone think of a more elegant way?

Comment: Can you provide your code

Comment: Does it matter? As mentioned at the end of my question, I know the double for loop works, but I don't like it. The optimal answer, if any, will work very differently from my current approach anyway. It's as if I'm asking for a quick sort algorithm while I'm using bubble sort. So what's the point of posting what I have right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
data = [
    {
        'prod_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_SP1',
        'testing_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_DA1',
        'project_adm': 'scisae',
        'vdb': 'aPWH - cpi',
        'db_name': 'cpi'
    },
    {
        'prod_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_SP1',
        'testing_instance': 'AEIS_PWH_DA1',
        'project_adm': 'scisae',
        'vdb': 'aPWH - aeis',
        'db_name': 'asis'
    }
]
res = {}
for i in data:
    # by @blhsing: tuple is easier and more efficient than string concatenation
    key = (i['prod_instance'], i['testing_instance'], i['project_adm'],)
    val = {
        'prod_instance': i['prod_instance'],
        'testing_instance': i['testing_instance'],
        'project_adm': i['project_adm'],
        'data_sources': []
    }
    data_sources = {
        'vdb': i['vdb'],
        'db_name': i['db_name']
    }
    res.setdefault(key, val)
    res[key]['data_sources'].append(data_sources)

result_list = list(res.values())
print(result_list)
```

Comment: Yep, it works great. And it is O(n). How come I missed the part that I can concat different keys into one.

It might be a bit too much, but is there some sort of shorthand(s) I can use to minimize that chunk of code? Sorry, I'm not too fimiliar with Python.

Comment: Key concatenation is prone to collisions. It would break if a record has keys whose components in the name overlap with those of another record. For example, if a record has `prod_instance` of `A_B` and `testing_instance` of `C`, it can collide with a record that has `prod_instance` of `A` and `testing_instance` of `B_C`. Unlikely to happen, but can. Better create a tuple from the composite keys instead.

Comment: @blhsing Yes, the purpose is to use a unique key. There are many methods, and character splicing is the simplest one.

Comment: You are right about that, but fortunately, I can guarantee the keys have a very strict format in this case. So for this specific case, collisions should be impossible to happen.

Comment: @Trock I'd argue that creating a tuple is easier and more efficient than string concatenation.

Comment: @MatthewKwong Can you use pandas? the groupby function of pandas is useful.

Comment: @blhsing Agree, no objection.